# How exactly does covariance and contravariance work in java streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

```
class User implements UserDetails
```

Why doesn't it work?

```
public Optional<UserDetails> getUserDetails(String username) {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userService.findByUsername(username);
        return userOptional;
}
```

.. but it works.

```
public Optional<UserDetails> getUserDetails(String username) {
    Optional<User> userOptional = userService.findByUsername(username);
    return userOptional.map(user -> user);
}
```

This also doesn't work.

```
public Optional<UserDetails> getUserDetails(String username) {
    Optional<User> userOptional = userService.findByUsername(username);
    return userOptional.stream().map(user -> user).findFirst();
}
```

The error occurs because `Optional<User>` cannot be converted to `Optional<UserDetails>`

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any streams in your question...?

Comment: The optional class does not belong to the streams? @Sweeper

Comment: No it does not "belong to the streams", whatever you mean by that phrase. `Optional` is just `Optional`.

Comment: Please post the *actual* error message. Is "The error occurs because Optional<User> cannot be converted to Optional<UserDetails>" the literal error message that is output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second code works because [`Optional.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) is declared like this:

```
public <U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T,? extends U> mapper)
```

It is a *generic* method declared to return any `Optional<U>`. In your code, the generic type parameter `U` is inferred from the return type of the `getUserDetails` method to be `UserDetails`. If you specify the type parameter explicitly, it becomes:

```
return userOptional.<UserDetails>map(user -> user);
```

Substituting `User` for `T` and `UserDetails` for `U`, we can see that `map` takes a parameter of type `Function<? super User,? extends UserDetails>`, i.e. a function that takes a `User` and returns a `UserDetails`. `user -> user`, the identity function, is such a function, because a `User` is always a `UserDetails`. Therefore the code compiles.

The first code does not compile because you cannot convert from `Optional<User>` to `Optional<UserDetails>`.

Note that there is no contravariance, or covariance, for that matter, involved in the second code. It compiles simply because `map` returns `Optional<U>`, where `U` is an inferred type parameter.

To be able to convert from `Optional<User>` to `Optional<UserDetails>`, you need covariance. Java only has use-site variance, so you can only achieve covariance by adding `? extends` to `Optional<UserDetails>`.

```
public Optional<? extends UserDetails> getUserDetails(String username) {
    Optional<User> userOptional = userService.findByUsername(username);
    return userOptional;
}
```

Similarly, for [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)), it is also a generic method.

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
```

However, in your third code, since the last call in `return` statement's expression is not `map`, the return type of the `getUserDetails` method is not used to infer `R`. `R` is simply inferred to be `User`, and `findFirst` returns `Optional<User>`.

Comment: But the last snippet could be fixed by specifying the intended type explicitly: `return userOptional.stream().<UserDetails>map(user -> user).findFirst();`